# JavaScript: errors when adding 0s (silence) to the begginning and end of audio arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, arraybuffer, mediastream

I am attempting to add silence before and after an audio file using javascript. My idea was to add zero values at the beginning and end of the audio. both of the methods I tried failed

Method 1, playback audio via AudioContext

```js
const context = new AudioContext()
    async function createSoundArray() {
      await fetch('file.mp3')
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
      .then(audioBuffer => {
        const data = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0) // Float32Array(100000)
        editAudio(data)
      });
    }
    createSoundArray()
    
   function editAudio(data){
    const editedData = []
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length + 50000; i++){// adds 25000 0 values (silence) to the begginning and end of array
          if( i > 25000 && i <= 125000){
            editedData.push(data[i - 25000])
          }else{
            editedData.push(0)      
          }
        }
        console.log(editedData) // array(150000)
        const Uint32 = Uint32Array.from(values)
        const audioCtx = new AudioContext()
        console.log(Uint32.buffer)// ArrayBuffer(150000)
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(pimbo.buffer, function (buf) { //error could not decode
          const playback = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
          playback.buffer = buf;
          playback.connect(audioCtx.destination);
          audioCtx.resume()
          console.log(playback.buffer)
        });
   }
```

This method resulted in the following error:

> The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.

Method 2, Playback audio via audio element

```js
const context = new AudioContext()
    async function createSoundArray() {
      await fetch('file.mp3')
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
      .then(audioBuffer => {
        const data = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0) // Float32Array(100000)
        editAudio(data)
      });
    }
    createSoundArray()
    
   function editAudio(data){
    const editedData = []
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length + 50000; i++){// adds 25000 0 values (silence) to the begginning and end of array
          if( i > 25000 && i <= 125000){
            editedData.push(data[i - 25000])
          }else{
            editedData.push(0)      
          }
        }
        const blob = new Blob(editedData)
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        audio.play()//error no supported source found
   }
```

This method resulted in the following error:

> Failed to play audio because no supported source was found

Because Both of these methods failed, this leads me to believe that the zeros added are causing the data to not be recognized as audio. However I don't understand why this is because I am simply adding zeros which are values that already exist inside the audio data before editing it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or why this is not working?